# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/indiamaz/public_html/musicwala.cf/get-zip.php on line 31

Tags: php, html

I created a php project a few days ago, when this error was not coming, but since 2 days this error is coming, I do not know what the problem is, please help someone.

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/indiamaz/public_html/musicwala.cf/get-zip.php on line 31

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /home/indiamaz/public_html/musicwala.cf/siteuploads/Gulabo Sitabo (2020) Mp3 Songs-musicwala.zip in /home/indiamaz/public_html/musicwala.cf/get-zip.php on line 51

##get-zip.php##

```
<?php
require_once('config/functions.php');
if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{
    if(!empty($_GET["code"]) == true)
    {
        $zipname = __dir__.'/siteuploads/'.$_GET["name"].'-musicwala.zip';
        if(file_exists($zipname))
        {
            $rp = str_replace(array("_","%20","+")," ",$_GET["name"]);
            $size = filesize($zipname);
            echo '
            
            <div id="dlzip"> <a class="dwnLink2" rel="nofollow" href="/siteuploads/'.$_GET["name"].'-musicwala.zip">download Zip Of '.$rp.' - '.vars::bytes($size).'</a>
                <center>    <b style="color:red">Note*Only 10 Files Compressed Due To Server Bandwidth Limition!</b></center></div>
            
            ';
            exit;
        }
        $url = vars::$siteUrl.$_GET["code"];
        $data = vars::cURL($url);
        $match  = preg_match_all("|<!-- WapkaHost.Com Web Solution :: File List -->(.*?)<!-- WapkaHost.Com Web Solution :: File List Complete -->|mis",$data,$cats);
        $rp = str_replace("/download/",vars::$siteUrl."download/",$cats[1][0]);
        preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $rp,$urls);
        $count = count($urls[1]);
        if($count < 12){
        //  $zipname = __dir__.'/siteuploads/'.$_GET["name"].'-musicwala.zip';
            $files="";
            foreach($urls[0] as $url)
            {
                $name = end(explode("/",$url));
            //  echo $name;
                $rm = preg_replace("|https://(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/{$name}|mis","http://musicwala.cf/files/download/id/$3",$url);
                $headers = get_headers($rm);
                $location = str_replace("Location: /","",$headers[3]);
                
                $files[] = $location;
            }
            
        
            $zip = new ZipArchive; $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
              
            foreach ($files as $file) 
            { 
            //  echo $file;
                $zip->addFile($file);
            }
         
            $zip->close();
            $rp = str_replace(array("_","%20","+")," ",$_GET["name"]);
            $size = filesize($zipname);
            echo '
            <div class="download">
            <div id="dlzip"> <a class="dwnLink2" rel="nofollow" href="/siteuploads/'.$_GET["name"].'-musicwala.zip">download Zip Of '.$rp.' - '.vars::bytes($size).'</a> </div>
            <center>    <b style="color:red">Note*Only 10 Files Compressed Due To Server Bandwidth Limition!</b></center>
            </div>
            ';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Sorry Max File Size Allow 10";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Faild To Compress!";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Strict Standards error on the `end` function, [from the documentation:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.phpn)

> Parameters (1)
>
> array. The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

`explode` is a function that returns an array - not a real variable, Since `end` modifies real variables, you must set the return value of `explode` to a separate real variable and send that variable to `end`.

```
// $url = __dir__.'/siteuploads/'.$_GET["name"].'-musicwala.zip';
   foreach($urls[0] as $url)
   {
       $exploded_array = explode("/", $url);
       $name = end( $exploded_array );
   // ...
```

As a guess, the OP's code should actually be `foreach ( $urls as $url ){` (not `$urls[0]`) but that isn't specifically related to the error code.

The second message: `Warning: filesize(): stat failed for..` is a bit harder to diagnose here. Possibly the file wasn't created, maybe it's too large (`filesize` can get weird over 2GB files), or some other issue. Try using the following to determine more of an error message ([docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstatusstring.php)).

```
var_dump( $zip->getStatusString() ); // Returns a string with the status message on success or false on failure.
var_dump( $zip->close() ); // Returns true on success or false on failure.
```